# How to remove everything before and after a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string stored as a variable and would like to edit it so everything before and after a certain part is removed.

An example of the string is : "apples pears bananas-123 grapes"

How can I remove everything apart from "bananas*" which i have stored as a variable.

Also, sometimes the target word will also change slightly so need to use wildcards for that part. e.g sometimes it will be bananas-2434 or bananas-111

I've been doing it in the following way but it doesn't really work correctly as sometimes i don't know the text that is before and after "bananas"

```
var c = "apples pears bananas grapes";
var el = c.replace('apples ', '');
var el2 = el.replace(' pears', '');
var el3 = el2.replace(' grapes', '');
```

Comment: If you are removing everything else, why not just check if the text exists (if required) and then overwrite the text entirely with the stored value?

Comment: Taking a step back, it's not clear to me what problem you're trying to solve.  Do you know the target substring in advance?  If so, why do you need to edit the original string down to that target substring, why not just use the known substring?  That is... In the example shown, if you know ahead of time that the string you want is `"bananas"`, then why can't you use that information and just use the string `"bananas"`?  Why does the larger string *need* to be reduced?

Comment: Sorry yes i dont know the target string, just a part of it, ive updated the post to include this.

Comment: @IslandScott: If you don't know the target substring then by what logic could you possibly reduce the overall string *to* that target substring?  Consider what you're asking of the code... "I need you to edit out everything except... *something*... but I can't tell you what."  I'm afraid it's still not clear what problem you're trying to solve.  Perhaps you could expand the contrived example to a more real example as a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I know part of the target substring. e.g i know it contains the words bananas but it could be bananas-123 or bananas-abc

Comment: @IslandScott: So then what you want is to parse out all text between any two space characters (or beginning/end of the string) which *contains* a known substring?

Comment: So you have a pattern to match, not a string, right? Is so you can use something like this `'akdfjksdjf bananas-23232 fskldjfk s'.match(/bananas-?\d*/)?.[0]` or `/bananas[-\w]*/`

Comment: Say i have the string "red blue green-467 black. I know theres a substring that contains "green" but i dont know what else the string contains. I somehow need to trim it down to "green-467"

Comment: The documentation has examples which use `.replace()` with a regular expression as you've been told in the comments. For future reference, why not look in the documentation too? You don't have to guess what everything does. Link: [MDN: JavaScript string replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could break the string into an array and check each value of the array like so.. Though it's not clear from your question if you want "bananas" or "bananas-2322" as a result.

```js
const theString = "apples pears bananas-2322 grapes"


const getTheTarget = (target, string) => {
  const theStringArray = string.split(" ");
  let result;
  for (const item of theStringArray) {
    if (item.includes(target)) {
      result = item;
      break
    }
  }
  return result
}

console.log("result :: ", getTheTarget("bananas", theString))
```